# Autowiring bean in Spring Boot Scheduler App

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-plugin, spring-scheduled

I am working on a spring boot scheduler app. The scheduling works fine, but I am unable to autowire the business logic bean from another module. I am getting the error "Unable to autowire MyService "

This is a multi module spring boot project.

MyService is an service implementation in another module

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppScheduler.class);
}
  }
```

AppScheduler.java

```
@EnableScheduling
public class AppScheduler{

@Autowired
MyService serv;

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")
public void performTaskUsingCron() throws Exception {

    serv.test();
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <groupId>my.service</groupId>  
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>      
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>test_BATCH</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>test_SERVICE</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are u using @Service in MyService?

```
@Service
public class MyService {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes.. it is  added

Comment: Oh! Then try add this to your main method: 
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

Comment: Yeah, SpringApplication.run... will define the beans in your application. It is part of Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the error is but I guess that you have to scan the Component present within the other module.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("co.uk.module.*")
public class Application  {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppScheduler.class);
  }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Note that the bean MyService must have the `@Service` (or `@Component`) annotation.

Comment: Yes.. the componentscan is happening .. But I guess the issue here is because the service component is in another module under the same package name

Answer (score 0):

I added some things to your classes, worked perfectly here:

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

AppScheduler.class:

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class AppScheduler {

    @Autowired
    private MyService serv;

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *")
    public void performTaskUsingCron() throws Exception {

        serv.test();
    }
}
```

MyService.class:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }
}
```

Comment: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean  .. i get this erorr on running this

Comment: Hmmmm... 

Remove @EnableScheduling from AppScheduler and add it to Application:

`@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application...`

If this doesn't work, try to implement CommandLineRunner in main class:

`@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

   @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}`